# Can you display all fields from a SharePoint list without writing them specifically?

Tags: 2013, client-object-model

Is it possible to retrieve every field value of a SharePoint List Item and display them on a web page without specifically calling them individually? I know it is possible to retrieve all the items but with JSOM and Rest you have to call each field you want displayed (ie oListItem.get_item('Title')). I would like all fields to appear automatically so if I add a new field it will appear without having to update the code.

Answer (score 2):

Get a list of fields first, then iterate them, if needed check for conditions (read only, visible etc.) and then display the values:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("ListName");
this.listFields = list.get_fields();
clientContext.load(this.listFields);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
    this.onListFieldsQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, 
    this.onListFieldsQueryFailed));

function onListFieldsQuerySucceeded() {
    var fieldEnumerator = listFields.getEnumerator();
    while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oField = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
        var fieldValue = oField.get_item(oField.internalName)
    }
}
```

Lookup field values are displayed in a different way, for example:

```
var fieldLookup = item.get_item('LastName');
var fieldLookupValue = fieldLookup.get_lookupValue();
```

So before getting the value of a field, check for it's type:

```
var fType = oField.get_fieldTypeKind();
if(fType === SP.FieldType.lookup) {
    oField.get_item('Department').get_lookupValue()
}
```

You can find SP.FieldType enumeration [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245640.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there any way to automatically iterate through all the fields without calling each ones internal name though?

Comment: He does not call them by name directly, look at the while loop. The LastName and Department are just an example for how to deal with lookup

Comment: Thanks I missed that.  But when I try to use this code I am getting an Uncaught TypeError: oField.get_item is not a function. I made sure sp.js was loaded before the function but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: then maybe the list hasn't been found

Comment: Might be many reasons. Try to debug the code line by line and see where it fails.

Comment: When I debug the code it looks like list.get_fields isn't returning anything. Everything else except the oField.get_item looks correct. Do I need to load the items too to make it work?